# How to show $g^{-1}Xg$ (conjugate) has an inverse?

Tags: group-theory

If $X$ is a subgroup of $G$, I want to show that an arbitrary element of the conjugate subgroup $g^{-1}xg$ has an inverse, so I need to show $(g^{-1}xg)^{-1}$ exists, but I cannot simply this expression since it's assumed we don't know if this is abelian or not. What should I do now?

Comment: You always have $(ab)^{-1} = b^{-1}a^{-1}$, so $(g^{-1}xg)^{-1} =$ ?

Comment: $g^{-1}x^{-1}g$

Comment: Right. So it is in $g^{-1}Xg$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is obvious that $(g^{-1}xg) (g^{-1}x^{-1}g)=(g^{-1}x^{-1}g)(g^{-1}xg)=e$, so that $g^{-1}xg$ and $gx^{-1}g^{-1}$ are inverses of one another.

All that remains to be shown is that $g^{-1}x^{-1}g$ is indeed in $g^{-1}Xg$. To see this, recall the definition of the set $g^{-1}Xg$:
$$g^{-1}Xg=\{h^{-1}yh \text{ such that } h\in G,y \in X\}$$
And let $h=g^{-1}$, $y=x^{-1}$. Since $G$ and $X$ are groups, $h \in G$ and $y \in X$, as we required.